# How should I structure my hiera for systemd limits?

Tags: puppet, systemd, hiera

I am trying to use https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-systemd.
I want to setup some systemd limits for a service so I have included ...

```
include ::systemd
```

... in my manifest.  And I have this hiera data:

```
systemd::service_limits:
    'openstack-nova-compute.service':
        limits:
                LimitNOFILE: 32768
```

But when puppet on my node I get this error:

```
Error while evaluating a Function Call, Class[Systemd]: parameter 'service_limits' unrecognized key 'openstack-nova-compute.service' at ...
```

I have looked at the docs and they do not explain how to form the hash in hiera, they just give this example:

```
::systemd::service_limits { 'foo.service':
  limits => {
    'LimitNOFILE' => 8192,
    'LimitNPROC'  => 16384,
  }
}
```

So how would I do that in hiera/yaml?

Comment: I want to say the problem is an invalid type is being specified here: https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-systemd/blob/master/manifests/init.pp#L36 (should be `Optional[Hash]`). I also note that this parameter is not being tested in the unit test matrix here: https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-systemd/blob/master/spec/classes/init_spec.rb. Also, their example directly uses the defined resource instead of passing in the parameter through the main class. In other words: three pieces of evidence point to a problem with the module. Someone else feel free to correct me.

Comment: I am afraid your right ... I'll open an issue at camptocamp's github for the systemd module.

Comment: More specifically, I think it should be `Optional[Hash[String, Hash]]`.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/ekohl agrees with you and has updated systemd ref. https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-systemd/issues/49

Comment: Awesome; glad that worked out for you. Looks like you will be good to go when the module gets a new version release. Also he added your specific use case to the unit test matrix, which is neat.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like ekohl used your suggested fix https://github.com/ekohl/puppet-systemd/commit/fe05278aa84e691fa48e745e741a9ca246b54820